# CMAKE dependency on upstream C++ Header-only library

Tags: c++, cmake, dependencies, header-only

I have a relatively simple header-only C++ library with the following structure

```
- apps
  - app
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - app.cpp
- include
CMakeLists.txt
```

The library itself is in the root of the project and `app1` is added afterwards. My intention here is to use the header-only library as a target referencing **include directories** and **link dependencies**.

Here's the root `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
project(myLib)

find_package( OpenGL REQUIRED )
find_package( GLEW REQUIRED )
find_package( Eigen3 REQUIRED )

# add the target
add_library( ${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE )
target_include_directories( ${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE . )
target_link_directories( ${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE OpenGL::OpenGL GLEW::glew Eigen3::Eigen )

# add apps
add_subdirectory(apps)
```

And the `CMakeLists.txt` file of the app:

```
project(app)

# find Qt5
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Gui Widgets OpenGL REQUIRED)

# add the exec
add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME} app.cpp )
target_include_directories( ${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE . )
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} myLib Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets Qt5::OpenGL )
```

Since `app1` is downstream from `myLib` I thought I can just add `myLib` to the link libraries of the app and it would configure everything automatically. This did not work and `app` could not see the **include directories** of `myLib`.

Any ideas how to fix this, or an explanation if the approach is wrong to begin with?

Thank you

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: indeed I did, thanks